# What's the proper way to clean the earpiece?

Tags: ear-piece

When I'm  just back from exercise, or work, and when I've used the earpiece they get really dirty or oily.   After I've bathed I don't want to use that same earpiece again without cleaning it properly.

Usually I'd take a tissue paper and just clean it.

Is there a proper way to clean the earpieces?

[image]

Comment: Ear-piece to what? Blue-tooth? Cellphone? Wig? Hearing aid?

Comment: Are you talking about Earbuds? What earpiece? Apathos beat me by 26 secs =>

Comment: @apathos i've edited the question

Comment: @UBhap look at the edit

Comment: Not really **computer** hardware, this is a very borderline question, normally you don't find questions about *just* the headphones or earphones on a site like Super User.  Thus why I closed.

Comment: ** Baby wipes  **

Comment: @Linker baby wipes?!

Comment: I vote to reopen. The question **is** borderline, but these devices can be used both on a computer and on other devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Earbuds

- Use a gentle cleaner, like soap and warm water. No need to go too heavy-duty here; try a mix of dishwashing detergent and water. (To wipe! Not to dunk!)
- Use a gentle cloth with just a small amount of the soap mixture. Too
  much soap could leave a residue on your earbuds, and too much water,
  well that goes without saying.
- If there's a lot of dirt or dust in the metal part of your earbuds,
  try brushing them with a dry toothbrush to dislodge the dust.
- Take a little rubbing alcohol and a q-tip. Barely wet the q-tip and clean the earbuds.

Also if you have just done some form of exercise and are really dirty then take a bath first! =>

Comment: http://www.goodhousekeeping.com/cm/goodhousekeeping/images/JVC-Gumy-blue-fb.jpg is called an earbud?

Comment: Ah I see. => Yes those are called earbuds. My answer gives you a few ways to clean them. Just be careful not to get them to wet.